# If Statement Not Applied Properly

Tags: javascript, html

My goal is to display 3 buttons and once 2 of them are clicked it will then display the corresponding content and hide the buttons. Here is my code. The problem is it never gets to the if statement. **Y** represents the number of clicks and **X** represents which values to display.

```js
var x = 0;
var y = 0;

function A() {
  var x = x + 1;
  console.log("+1");
  var y = y + 1;
}

function B() {
  var x = x + 10
  console.log("+10");
  var y = y + 1;
}

function C() {
  var x = x + 100;
  console.log("+100");
  var y = y + 1;
}
if (y = 2) {
  document.getElementById("ButtonA").className += "hide";
  document.getElementById("ButtonB").className += "hide";
  document.getElementById("ButtonB").className += "hide";
  console.log("Hide Buttons A-C")
} else if (x = 11) {
  document.getElementById("A").className += " display";
  document.getElementById("B").className += " display";
  console.log("Display A+B");
} else if (x = 101) {
  document.getElementById("A").className += " display";
  document.getElementById("C").className += " display";
  console.log("Display A+C");
} else if (x = 110) {
  document.getElementById("B").className += " display";
  document.getElementById("C").className += " display";
  console.log("Display B+C");
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}

.display {
  display: block;
}

.w3-col {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">

<h1 class="w3-center">Banks</h1>
<div class="w3-row-padding w3-center">
  <button onclick="A()" id="ButtonA">A</button>
  <button onclick="B()" id="ButtonB">B</button>
  <button onclick="C()" id="ButtonC">C</button>
</div>
<br>
<div class="w3-row-padding">
  <div class="w3-col l4 s4 w3-center" id="A">
    <div class="w3-container w3-red">
      <h1>A</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="w3-col l4 s4 w3-center" id="B">
    <div class="w3-container w3-green">
      <h1>B</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="w3-col l4 s4 w3-center" id="C">
    <div class="w3-container w3-blue">
      <h1>C</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use == for comparison, = is for assignment.

Comment: It does get to the if statement. As soon as you load the page and then never again.

Comment: Better yet use `===` for type safe comparison. `==` does automatic type conversion, `=` is for assignment.

Comment: apart from the error with "=" sign, you will have to re-trigger the "if" logic every time user clicks one of the button, so you should wrap it in some function and call it in your A,B,C functions

Comment: `var x = x + 1;` -> `x = x + 1;` (the same for the other additions)

Comment: document.getElementById("A") should be changed to document.getElementById("ButtonA"), etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments you need to -

- Use `==` or `===` in your if/else as a comparator, as `=` is a setter
- Trigger the if/else section after updating the values
- don't redeclare using `var` inside the function, as they are already declared at the top of your JavaScript

That said, your if/else logic is a little wonky.  For example, any two clicks set `y` equal to `2`.  Everything gets hidden (if you fix your typo of adding `hide` to `#ButtonB` twice.  If you want, I can help you fix that, but this should get you close to your goal.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    .hide {
      display: none;
    }
    
    .display {
      display: block;
    }
    
    .w3-col {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;

    function A() {
      x = x + 1;
      console.log("+1");
      y = y + 1;
      check();
    }

    function B() {
      x = x + 10
      console.log("+10");
      y = y + 1;
      check();
    }

    function C() {
      x = x + 100;
      console.log("+100");
      y = y + 1;
      check();
    }

    function check() {
      console.log("y=", y, "x=", x)
      if (y == 2) {
        document.getElementById("ButtonA").className += "hide";
        document.getElementById("ButtonB").className += "hide";
        document.getElementById("ButtonC").className += "hide";
        console.log("Hide Buttons A-C")
      } else if (x == 11) {
        document.getElementById("A").className += " display";
        document.getElementById("B").className += " display";
        console.log("Display A+B");
      } else if (x == 101) {
        document.getElementById("A").className += " display";
        document.getElementById("C").className += " display";
        console.log("Display A+C");
      } else if (x == 110) {
        document.getElementById("B").className += " display";
        document.getElementById("C").className += " display";
        console.log("Display B+C");
      }
    }
  </script>
  <h1 class="w3-center">Banks</h1>
  <div class="w3-row-padding w3-center">
    <button onclick="A()" id="ButtonA">A</button>
    <button onclick="B()" id="ButtonB">B</button>
    <button onclick="C()" id="ButtonC">C</button>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="w3-row-padding">
    <div class="w3-col l4 s4 w3-center" id="A">
      <div class="w3-container w3-red">
        <h1>A</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-col l4 s4 w3-center" id="B">
      <div class="w3-container w3-green">
        <h1>B</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-col l4 s4 w3-center" id="C">
      <div class="w3-container w3-blue">
        <h1>C</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There're at least two things I can see:

1. `script` tag is read by js. More than that, it's read right before the buttons are renderred.
2. `if` statement is executed too. But at the moment of checking there're no values that would lead the code execution to one of the flows
3. When you type `var x` inside of a function, it's declared as a local variable, that's why it'll store always the same value.

Instead of this, you should declare a separate function that would check the values:

```
function doCheck(){
    var buttonA = document.getElementById("ButtonA"),
        buttonB = document.getElementById("ButtonB"),
        buttonC = document.getElementById("ButtonC");
    if (y = 2) {
                buttonA.className += "hide";
                buttonB.className  += "hide";
                buttonC.className += "hide";
                console.log("Hide Buttons A-C")
            } else if (x = 11) {
                buttonA.className += " display";
                buttonB.className += " display";
                console.log("Display A+B");
            } else if (x = 101) {
                buttonA.className += " display";
                buttonC.className += " display";
                console.log("Display A+C");
            } else if (x = 110) {
                buttonB.className += " display";
                buttonC.className += " display";
                console.log("Display B+C");
            }
}
```

Now, invoke the function inside of all those three functions (with some corrections of the code):

```
function A() {
      x = x + 1;
      console.log("+1");
      y = y + 1;
      doCheck();
    }

function B() {
  x = x + 10
  console.log("+10");
  y = y + 1;
  doCheck();
}

function C() {
  x = x + 100;
  console.log("+100");
  y = y + 1;
  doCheck();
}
```

*advice 1* Give the functions more understandable names, while debugging it'll be much more easier to read the code.

*advice 2* Instead of accessing elements by id all the time and wasting your time with writing almost the same code, just declare corresponding variables at the top of the function and refer to **variables** representing elements